# Mocking functions in python called from a dictionary

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a problem with the code below. I would like to mock the functions in different file for unit testing in the FUNCTION_MAPPING part.

```
import module.module2 as module_name

FUNCTION_MAPPING = {
1: module_name.foo,
2: module_name.foo2,
3: module_name.foo3
}

def my_func(number):
    function_call = FUNCTION_MAPPING[number]
    result = function_call()
    return result
```

For some reason I can not mock those functions. I have tried every possible way that i had knowledge about. If possible i would like not to change the code above.

foo, foo2 and foo3 inner code can be anything print(1), print(2) etc

Code of the unit test:

```
@patch("module_of_the_code_above.module_name.foo",return_value="Test")
def test_my_func(self,mocked_foo):
    result = my_func(1)
    nose_tools.assert_equal(result,"Test")
```

Comment: Do you have an error ? What is the code of foo, foo2, and foo3 functions ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example, including code for `module.module2` and your unit test.

Comment: module.module2 is just a module where the functions  foo, foo2, foo3 are. the inner code of these functions is inrelevant for the question.

Comment: it is relevant because the way the functions are being imported matter -  `from foo import bar` and `import foo.bar` have different namespace consequences, both in your code and in your unit test. Please provide **the exact code that replicates your error** (incl. imported functions and unit tests) so that we can test it, instead of blindly assuming how you are defining things.

Comment: I have updated the question but this is the best i can do. I can not share the original code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple two options if you use MagicMock:

The issue with this case is that as you import your module the dictionary with the lookups is created and the references to the "module_name.foo" is made, so any patching/mocking at a global level will not affect that explicit mapping, you have to replace/wrap it on that structure.

```
....

# in you test manually replace the function mapping with either new
# functions you define, but I prefer MagicMock as it allows you to get
# all kinds of goodies.
# This is necessary as the dict for the function lookup is probably already
# initialize before any mocking can take place (as you include the module)
# and so even patching the function globally will not affect that lookup

# You can use MagicMock so that your original function is not used..
FUNCTION_MAPPING['1'] = mock.MagicMock()
FUNCTION_MAPPING['2'] = mock.MagicMock()
FUNCTION_MAPPING['3'] = mock.MagicMock()

# Or

# if you just want to spy/keep stats but still call the original function, you will 
# need to do something like 
FUNCTION_MAPPING['1'] = mock.Mock(wraps=FUNCTION_MAPPING['1')

# then you can all the great things that you can do with mock. 
assert FUNCTION_MAPPING['1'].call_counts == 3
```

PS: did not have time to test/vet the this for exact syntax but hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You should assign the function(without brackets) and not the result of the fucntion - `{1: func}`

```
def hello():
    print('Hello!')

def text(text):
    print(text)

function_map = {
    1: hello,
    2: text
}

func1 = function_map[1]
func1()

func2 = function_map[2]
func2('ABC123')
```

Output:

```
Hello!
ABC123
```

When working with imports:

```
import math

function_map = {
    'factorial': math.factorial,
    'gcd': math.gcd
}

func1 = function_map['factorial']
print(func1(5))

func2 = function_map['gcd']
print(func2(5, 25))
```

Comment: OP's issues don't seem related to calling the functions from the dictionary, but rather to mocking the dictionary when unit-testing.

Comment: the problem is that i can not mock the functions inside the dictionary.